# Is the word order correct in "I'm not sure what is the right way" or is it only correct to say "I'm not sure what the right way is"?

Tags: grammaticality, word-order, questions, subject-verb-inversion, wh-questions

I believe "I'm not sure what the right way is" is grammatically correct.

Recently I've seen too many people writing it this way:

> I'm not sure what is the right way.

Is it grammatically correct as well? Maybe in a different sense? Or simply misuse by non-native speakers?

Comment: Suspected duplication. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50006/lets-see-how-can-we-do-this/

Comment: @JohnMLawler Haha funny. That was my question asked couple of days ago :)

Comment: @JohnMLawler I don't know, that one is a bit different, about the positioning of *we* and *can* in that sentence.

Comment: OK, if it's not gonna get closed out from under me, I'll answer it.

Comment: It's not a duplicate because the sentence in that linked question is ungrammatical, but this one is grammatical.

Comment: @alcas Eight years later, here I come to tell you that both sentences will be considered ungrammatical by many speakers, while many other speakers will find both grammatical. To me, they’re both quite ungrammatical, but I know people who would use both without a moment’s hesitation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the inversion in “Let’s see ʜᴏᴡ ᴄᴀɴ ᴡᴇ do this” an error for “Let’s see ʜᴏᴡ ᴡᴇ ᴄᴀɴ do this”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50006/is-the-inversion-in-let-s-see-%ca%9c%e1%b4%8f%e1%b4%a1-%e1%b4%84%e1%b4%80%c9%b4-%e1%b4%a1%e1%b4%87-do-this-an-error-for-let-s-see-%ca%9c%e1%b4%8f%e1%b4%a1-%e1%b4%a1)

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/608581/2085).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Everybody learns that *What is the right way?* is a *Wh*-Question structure. Add the intonation (which is what the question mark is for), and the context, and it's ordinary. As a **question**.  It's formed from something like *The right way is X*, where the unknown *X* becomes *what*.

But as the [Object Complement](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/aue/complmnt.html) of a mental or communicational predicate, like *know, be sure,* or *say*, it's **embedded in** the sentence, rather than **being** the sentence. That makes it an Embedded Question (aka Headless Relative or *Wh*-Clause), and that's a standard complement type, with slightly different syntax from ordinary questions.

The slight difference is that the normal Question-Formation rule inverts the Subject and the first auxiliary verb

> [with two caveant:
>
> 1. *be* is always an auxiliary verb
> 2. if there isn't an auxiliary verb, invoke *Do*-Support]

while an Embedded Question normally does *not* invert.

- *Where **are they**? ~ I'm not sure where **they are**.*

**But**, just in case the sentence is intended by the speaker to request information (rather than to merely comment on one's mental deficiency), one way of many that this indirect request can be signalled as a question is to use the **other** question structure, the one that actually resembles a question, **with** inversion, instead of without inversion.

- *I'm not sure where **are they**.* (means "Where are they?")

This is frequently intoned like a question instead of a statement, and punctuated with ? to mark this.

And **that** has become a very widespread pragmatic convention in the last 40 years or so, though it still varies locally and socially. And that's all, really. Both are correct, though they don't mean the same thing, pragmatically.

Comment: I think at least some people writing *"I'm not sure what is the right way"* are hypercorrecting because of the imagined dangling participle "rule", i.e. they don't want to end a sentence with *"is"*.

Comment: I'm afraid that's true of a vast number of variant constructions. Who knows **what** kind of zombie rules people have been taught? 
The best anyone can do, I think, is point out real phenomena and how they work, with some attention to known variants. 
After all, we all make up our own language, and then spend the rest of our lives trying to pass as English speakers.

Comment: @JohnMLawler Very well said!

Comment: If the stress is intended to be, "I'm not sure what _is_ the right way," then the phrase would be correct, although it would be difficult to read it that way. (Or does this fall under your "pragmatic convention?")

Comment: To me, "I'm not sure what is the right way" sounds much correct than "I'm not sure where they are", so I'm not sure the analogy is good.

Maybe this is why: You stated that the question is derived from something like "The right way is X". I think that's the derivation of "I'm not sure what the right way is". However, you can also say "X is the right way", which generates "I'm not sure what is the right way" when you turn it into a question. They're both grammatical to preserve the contrast between those two possible underlying forms.

Comment: @alcas Thanks. I think you are hitting the nail on the head.

Comment: In third paragraph, what's your rationale for using Latin plural *[caveant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/caveant)* instead of English *[caveats](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/caveats)*?

Comment: @jwpat7 Because it’s kinda cool to use obscure plurals.  My favourite is “octopodes”.

Comment: _Caveat_ is a verb; it's the 3sg subjunctive present form of the verb _cavēre_ 'beware'. _Caveant_ is the 3pl.

Comment: @JohnLawler But *I'm not sure where are they* does not sound grammatical, nor idiomatic, to me here in Britain. Nor does *I'm not sure what is the right way*. But *I'm not sure which is the right way* sounds perfectly fine.

Comment: "I'm not sure what's the right way" strikes my ear as marginal. This kind of statement isn't the kind where you have to "unlearn" how you actually say it in order to be "correct"; rather, native speakers know how to say "I'm not sure what the right way **is**" without having to think about it.

Comment: @alcas: I take it this is just a typo:  "much correct" and you're a native speaker?

Comment: Seems to me "I'm not sure what is the right way" is something people say when they are questioning their own instincts and trying to be "correct", afraid that **is** dangling at the end of the sentence like that (*I don't know what the right way **is***) is "bad writing".

Comment: Maybe they use *I don't know what is the right way* to emphasize on *is*.

Comment: You've closed [another question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/613929/when-would-be-autocorrection) as a dupe of this one. But neither of the choices in the other question involve subject auxiliary inversion!

Comment: Go back and look, please. Anyway, I just thought I was voting for closure. I hadn't ever proposed a duplicate before and didn't know it caused instant closure.

Comment: @JohnLawler You've recently earned the only ever awarded gold badge for "grammar" (a tag they basically tried to ban at one point!). That now means you have a golden hammer. If you vote to close a Q it gets instantly closed. Likewise, I believe, with re-opening. [I did go back and check, btw. No SAI!]

Comment: Oh, dear. I didn't ask for that. I dislike the badges as much as I do the tags they're based on. Can I give it back?