# When do "direct" and "indirect" questions become the same?

Tags: indirect-question

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“I'm not sure what the right way is”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51123/im-not-sure-what-the-right-way-is)

Direct and indirect questions are not usually the same:

> **What is** your name?
>  I don't know **what** your name **is**.

But sometimes, they become the same:

> **What is** wrong with you?
>  I don't know **what is** wrong with you.
>
> **What is** available?
>  I like to know **what is** available.

So my question is, what the grammatical rule is when they become the same.

Comment: Pretty much the same question as in http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51123/im-not-sure-what-the-right-way-is/51126#51126

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be very confused.  Grammatically, "I don't know what your name is." and "I don't know what is wrong with you." are not questions.  Of course, if I say, "I don't know xxx." in a situation where it is normal for somebody to tell me xxx, then the statement functions as a question, but that's a matter of context and usage, not grammar.

Simple statements:

> **I don't know what your name is**, and I don't want to know either.  I prefer anonymity.
>
> I have run every medical test, and they are all negative.  I cannot explain your symptoms.  **I don't know what is wrong with you.**

Statements functioning as questions:

> I'm sorry, but you have the advantage of me.  **I don't know what your name is.**
>
> I can't help you if you won't explain your problem.  **I don't know what is wrong with you.**