# What is the meaning of 'they' and 'got to' in 'You'll never guess who they got to replace you at work'?

Tags: meaning, grammar, pronouns

> You'll never guess who they got to replace you at work.

The sentence above is from the dialogue in the series *The Big Bang Theory*.
I can guess the meaning is that you will never guess who will work instead of you.
But I want to know what's the meaning of 'got to'.
And what does 'they' indicate?

I think the following sentence is correct grammatically.

> You'll never guess who will replace you at work.

Comment: The [“I'm not sure what the right way is”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51123/im-not-sure-what-the-right-way-is) question deals with embedded question object complements.

Comment: get can mean find. [...]who they found to replace you at work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

- *Get* here is probably used in the sense "obtain", equivalent to  "hire" or "engage". If that is the case, *to replace you* is an infinitival of purpose: it says why *who* was hired, as your replacement. *They* is the subject of *replace*.
- It is also possible that *get* is used in the sense "induce" or "persuade". If that is the case, then *to replace you* designates the action which *who* was induced to undertake. *Who* (more precisely, the missing value which the variable *who* points to) is the subject of *replace*.

Comment: Thank you for your meticulous answer. I fully understood the sentence i asked. "You'll never guess / who they got / to replace you / at work." Actually i saw 'got to' as a one chunk before. Thanks.

Comment: @Danny_Kim Yes, your understanding was correct; you just didn't see how you got there! :)

Answer (score 1):

'they' is, I suspect, 'the powers that be'.