# Is it grammatically correct [nowadays] not to invert the NP and copula in an indirect question?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, american-english, north-american-english

I don't know if this is a recent phenomenon, but for the last decade, I've noticed when English speakers make statements denoting there are/were unknowns, they usually phrase them with a question within them, but it always sounds off to me, so I'm wondering if this way of making statements is grammatically correct.

- People say "We don’t know what are the limitations of technology.", but I expect

"We don't know what the limitations of technology are."

- People say "They want to figure out what are the variables.", but I expect

"They want to figure out what the variables are."

- People say "The first step is knowing where is the house.", but I expect

"The first step is to know where the house is."

Comment: “People” are wrong.  I find it hard to believe that native English speakers would say these. Sometimes in stream of consciousness speech things don’t come out just right those are excusable.

Comment: These sentences all sound like they were written by non-native English speakers. I'd assume that they correspond to the grammar of their native language.

Comment: These sentences sound commonplace in spoken English. People talk the way they talk, and no amount of censure is going to change that. I wouldn't use them in a college thesis, but any but the most hidebound prescriptivist can be heard uttering such constructions.

Comment: I answered [this one long ago](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/51126/15299); it turns out to be a common way of asking a real question.