# When can an embedded interrogative clause exhibit Subject-Auxiliary Inversion?

Tags: questions, subject-verb-inversion, subordinate-clauses

I found in a comic book an interesting example of an embedded interrogative that had Subject-Auxiliary Inversion (SAI): [I'm not too sure what exactly is it that you're asking.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWc5B.jpg) Is this Standard English or a dialect thing? I know embedded SAI is found in Northern England, but this is presumably an American example. Are there any special environments in which we may find embedded SAI?

Comment: Inversion is sometimes found in AmE (but not normally in BrE) in contexts of strong question-orientation. Cf. also "Ed asked what had he done wrong" / "She wanted know was he ill".

Comment: If the embedded question is actually intended to solicit an answer, [it can optionally invert](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/51126/15299) to signal this pragmatically.