# Indirect questions with question mark

Tags: indirect-question

Is this an indirect question:

> You are probably wondering, what are they staring at?

My instinct is to add a question mark, since, if you changed the construction to,

> You are probably asking, "What are they staring at?"

I would want to add a question mark.  But I'm not sure of the answer, which is why I'm asking you folks.

Comment: Failure to invert an embedded question, combined with question intonation, is a [different construction, a somewhat indirect way to ask a question](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/51126/15299).

Answer (score 4):

That's not an indirect question. It's a direct question.

An [indirect question](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/do-you-know-what-an-indirect-question-is) is a question at one remove, using phrases like

- Can/Could you tell me…?
- Do you know…?
- Would you mind…?
- Do you have any idea…?
- Would it be possible…?

In these cases, the question is that first phrase, and a question mark is appropriate.

In your example, "What are they staring at?" is a direct question and should be punctuated as your instinct tells you.

Note that "You are probably wondering..." is not a question, so it doesn't form an indirect question. It is a statement, and the object of *wondering* is a noun phrase, in this case "what they are staring at".

Comment: The OP asked whether "You are probably wondering..." was a question, so your first sentence is potentially confusing. You give the answer only as an afterthought!

Comment: @KateBunting Actually he asks, "Is this an indirect question?" and my first sentence is "It is not an indirect question." I think the answer is structured correctly, but in any case an answer should be taken as a whole.

Comment: Sorry - I had misread it as _You are probably wondering what they are staring at_.