# Embedded phrases and clauses in "May I know..." questions

Tags: questions, modal-verbs

Hello everyone and thank you for your consideration. I am a professional English teacher and I usually can find answers for every grammar question, but I have one student that is very good at coming up with questions to stump me. I believe I'm on the right track with this one, but I would really appreciate some confirmation.

The question is the difference between these two:

1. May I know what your name is?
2. May I know what is in your hand?

I've already searched and read multiple posts here, including this one:
["I'm not sure what the right way is"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51123/im-not-sure-what-the-right-way-is/51126#51126)

I've already explored the basic sentence with the student (May I know 'something') and that there is an embedded phrase/clause in the object. **Is the answer simply that the first example has an embedded phrase and the second has an embedded clause?**

I also explored with them the difference between

3. May I know what your hand is? (Imagine a game of cards)
4. May I know what is in your hand?

In the embedded phrase/clause, it definitely seems to be a matter of whether there is a noun phrase ("your hand") or any other kind of word/phrase (like the prepositional phrase "in your hand," an adjective, verb, etc.). Am I on the right track?

Comment: The first can be "May I know your name".

Comment: No, they are both embedded clauses. The first inquires about your name, the second about the contents of your hand.

Comment: If you are asking why (1) uses "... what [phrase] **is**" and (2) uses "what **is** [phrase]", the answer is that the two *what*'s  represent very different parts of the sentence. You might think that we could look at the non-embedded versions of these interrogatives. However, these look as if they have the same type of phrase  order "What **is**your name" and "What **is** in your hand." However, in the 1st example the subject is "your name". It appears after the word **is** because of subject auxiliary inversion.

Comment: (cont) The word *what* occurs at the very beginning because of the rule that says that the *wh-* word should appear at the front. If the *wh*-word 'moves' to the front we get subject auxiliary inversion. In the second example, the subject is the word "what". It occurs at the beginning already by virtue of being the subject as in a normal sentence. This co-incides with the *wh*-word first rule. There is no subject auxiliary inversion.  However, in embedded interrogatives such as (1), subject auxiliay inversion is not allowed and so the subject occurs *before* the verb **is**, just like in (2).

Comment: @Jack I think it's time that you responded to the comments and answers.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Re your 2nd comment. In the main clause interrogative "What is your name", it is possible to label "what" as subject and "your name" as PC, i.e. deriving from the declarative "X is your name". Less likely perhaps, but still grammatical.

Comment: @BillJ Ah, but not if that’s the corresponding main clause version of OP’s subordinate one, though! Because the subordinate one would have had to have been  “May I ask what is your name” :-)

Comment: The corresponding main clause of the OP's subordinate one can only be "What is your name?", where "what" can be interpreted as subject or PC depending on whether it is derived from "X is your name" or "Your name is X".

Comment: @Billj But the corresponding main clause cannot have “your name” as a PC, because in that case the subordinate one it corresponds to would likewise be  “what is your name” because it would follow the same subject copula PC order!

Comment: I'm saying that the interrogative main clause "What is your name?" can be analysed in either of two ways (S-V-PC or PC-V-S) depending on which declarative equivalent it is seen to derive from. The subordinate clause equivalent can be phrased in either of two ways ("what your name is" or "what is your name") -- it's a free choice. But let's wait until the OP responds to the comments and answers. I suspect they are now confused and probably won't bother.

Comment: @BillJ Hmm. I'm saying that the main clause S-V-PC can only have the subordinate clause version S-V-PC. If there's no SAI in the main clause, there can't be in the subordinate one. No?

Comment: @BillJ - thank you for all your interactions to help me understand this, I didn't even suspect that "what" would be used in different ways between these examples. I'm new to StackExchange, and so I hope I'm doing this correctly; I will add another reply to my question to try to summarize everyone's thoughts.

Comment: @Jack I believe it's against the rules to post an answer to your own question.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. - thank you for all your contributions and really helping me understand this better. I confess that at first these explanations were at the boundaries of my grammar ability, but after rereading everyone's contributions, I think I'm starting to form an understanding. I'll reply to my post to try to compile everyone's thoughts!

Comment: @BillJ Actually, surprisingly perhaps, it's not against the rules to answer one's own question. In fact SE actively encourage it! If you look at the bottom of the page under one of your questions, you'll see that the answer button actually say "Answer your own question"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My initial thoughts:

1a. You wouldn't say this.  While it is technically correct I don't think I have every heard the phrase "May I know..." in spoken English.  I can't really think of any times you would use the phrase unless you are really stressing the situation in some way, such as in legal issues, secrets or maybe not wanting to cause terror/an attack - e.g. "may I know your name, or is that not possible at this time...?"

1b. You would instead say something like, "can I see...", "can you tell me..."

However to answer the your question if you do want to use the phrase :

2 The standard word order for questions in English is inverted:

```
 S+V+O/Predicate ---> interrogative(+Predicate)+Auxiliary+S+V
```

E.g. "I am playing football." ---> "What are you doing?"

E.g. "I am feeling happy." ---> "How are you feeling?"

```
But with a preposition/adverb-phrase ---> the same inversion but the PP/AP is kept at the end
```

E.g. "I am playing in the pool" ---> "What are you doing (in the pool)?"

E.g. I am feeling at school/this month?" ---> "How are you feeling (at school/this month)?"

3 To then move to indirect questions:

```
In an indirect question, there is no word order inversion, they simply start with the interrogative
```

E.g "What are you doing?" ---> "He wants to know what you are doing." <--- "I am playing football."

E.g. "How are you feeling?" ---> "May I know how you are feeling?" <--- "I am feeling happy."

The rule for PP and AP is the same, they stay at the end

Hope this helps

Comment: I disagree. Subordinate interrogatives normally have no inversion.

Comment: Ah true, let me change it, the inversion is not for subordinate questions, as you say, but standard interrogatives.

Comment: "May I know" is reasonably common in spoken English, if a little formal.

Comment: @Chenmunka Depends on what you mean by reasonably common. I don't think I've ever run across it in the wild.

Answer (score 3):

In both your examples, you have embedded ***clauses***. I think the difference lies in the function of ***what***. In the first sentence it is not the subject but the predicative complement of the verb of the embedded clause, as I was kindly shown in the comments, whereas in the second it is the subject of the embedded clause.

Quoting the *Collins COBUILD English Usage*, [FreeDictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/what#:%7E:text=You%20use%20what%20when%20you,the%20object%20of%20a%20preposition.) says

> When you use ***what*** as a ***pronoun***, it can be ***the subject***, object, or ***complement of a verb.*** It can also be the object of a preposition.
>
> - ***What*** happened to the crew? [subject]
> - ***What*** is your name? [predicative complement]

In the sentence

> May I know ***what*** your ***name*** is?

*what* is the predicative complement of *is*, and *name* is the subject of *is*.

Whereas in

> May I know ***what is*** in your hand?

***what*** functions as subject. So it is natural that in the embedded clause *[what is in your hand]*, the subject *what* should be followed by its verb *is* and then by the complement *in your hand*.

Comment: It's certainly nothing to do with "may I know", and everything to do with "what": "He told me what was in his hand" vs "He told me what his name was".

Comment: In  "May I know [what your name is]?", the subject of the interrogative is "your name" and  "what" is predicative complement.

Comment: @BillJ That's also where my research got me to!

Answer (score 3):

> [1] *May I know* [*what your name is*]?
>
> [2] *May I know* [*what is in your hand*]?

In both examples the bracketed elements are subordinate interrogative clauses (embedded questions) functioning as complement of "know".

Internally, there is no subj-aux inversion in either example. in [1] the NP "your name" is subject and the pronoun "what" is complement. In [2] the pronoun "what" is subject and the PP "in your hand" is complement.

The meanings are, respectively:

> "May I know the answer to the question 'What is your name?'"
>
> "May I know the answer to the question 'What is in your hand?'"

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Certainly not from me as your post is, of course, factually impeccable. I think, though, that the OP's concern is the (apparently )different phrase order of the two clauses. I understand that this is implied by your answer, but I'm not sure that it's clear for those readers who aren't grammar aficionados. In fact it might be even more confusing because the phrase order in the two main clause interrogatives that you give superficially seems identical (which may in fact be the source of OP's confusion. They both have the superficial order "What" plus "be" plus "X phrase:"