# "when would be..." autocorrection

Tags: syntactic-analysis, word-order

I have just been autocorrected as follows:

I wrote: "Please let me know when would be a good time to..."

Correction: "Please let me know when a good time would be to..."

I suppose I can see that both of these are acceptable, but I cannot see that mine is wrong or even that the correction is preferable.

I see mine as having a structure where "a good time to x" forms a noun phrase.

The correction, I suppose has "to x" as an adverbial? Perhaps a simplistic definition.

Am I wrong about either of these? Is mine in fact not a viable noun phrase? Is the correction doing something other than I suggest?

In any case, I prefer mine because I think it benefits from the proximity of "a good time" and "to do something" and where the correction creates distance between these, I think it is poorer for it. Is this valid or jus wishful thinking on my part?

Comment: I find your version perfectly idiomatic.

Comment: See my comment under the L:PH answer.

Comment: This should not be closed as a duplicate of the linked to post. That their post over on the other page is about subject auxiliary inversion, according to @JohnLawler. However, there is no subject auxiliary inversion in this question here. So by definition that answer cannot answer this question.

Comment: @Araucaria-Him The auxiliary is _would_ and it appears in the subordinate clause. The subject of that clause is _a good time_ and _would_ appears on both sides of it in the examples. The resemblance of the uninverted _would_ to a real question makes it more appropriate pragmatically when actually seeking information. If not subject-aux inversion here, what would you suggest to describe the phenomenon?

Comment: Whoops! I meant the **inverted** _would_, as in a real, impositive, question, not just a _wh-_ complement, where inversion is not normal.

Comment: It seems to be that "*Please let me know when would be a good time to X*" is equivalent to the question as a main clause: “*When would be a good time to X*" where **"When**" is the s**ubject of specifying "be"**. In contrast, "*Please let me know when a good time to X would be*" is equivalent to the question: “*When would a good time to X be*" where **"When" is the complement of specifying "be".**

Comment: Seems unlikely to me. Adverb clauses can only be complements in special circumstances. What's special here? Try it with _He'll tell me_ instead of _I'd like to know_. Same analysis?

Comment: @JohnLawler Not really, *would* does not appear next to the subject in *when would be a good time ...* because the verb *be* intervenes. What we have seems to be one of two things. It could be a case of subject-dependent inversion as in "*In the doorway appeared the silhouette*" or the two choices might represent two different questions: "*After Christmas would be a good time*" and "*A good time would be after Christmas*" where the interrogative *when* replaces the PP *after Christmas* in each case and the two clauses appear as embedded questions/subordinate interrogative clauses.

Comment: @JohnLawler The SAI version would be "*Please let me know when **would** a good time **be** to ...*".

Comment: @Araucaria-Him Does your analysis agree with mine to some extent or not quite?

Comment: @user424874 I think your analysis looks correct. Of course, *when* can occur easily (and often does) as a complement of *be* because it's not an advert but a preposition. Maybe you should write an answer?

Comment: @Araucaria-Him Wow! That made my day. I have nothing else to add and I'm not that articulate but I may try. If in case I can manage one and you find it unsatisfactory, please write a better one. :)

Comment: @Araucaria-Him Posted one! Hope it's not that confusing...

Answer (score 3):

> (**CoGEL § 15.5**) **Notes** [b] In literary style, subject-verb inversion occasionally occurs when the wh-element is the subject complement or an obligatory adverbial, parficularly if the subject is lengthy:
>
> - She told us how strong was her motivation to engage in research.
> - It took me some time to discover in which village stood the memorial to our fallen comrades.

"When" is the subject complement of "would be": "a good time to…  would be < when >". Therefore, the subject "a good time to…" being of that sort that can be called long, the inversion is correct, and even preferable.

- Please let me know when would be a good time (to collect the bulk of this information). (*preferable, to say the least*)
- Please let me know when a good time (to collect the bulk of this information)  would be. (*sounds somewhat awkward, not "well connected"*)

<sub>**CoGEL**: *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English language*</sub>

Comment: When would be a good time to do [whatever] is **a question form**.  Please let me know when a good time would be to do [whatever]..."= a statement form. The utterance is not literary. Also, the *subject is not lengthy*.

Comment: "When would be a good time to do this?" **is** a question form, but not "when would be a good time to do this", it is not. Compare: "I asked him **when would be a good time to do the repairs on the roof of the house and on the old outbuildings**." and "He knew **when would be a good time to do the repairs on the roof of the house and on the old outbuildings**.";  the bolded parts are the same in both cases. // The inversion tends to occur _particularly_ if the subject is lengthy. // I agree with you about the stipulation "in literary style"; it seems that literary style is not the sole case.

Comment: Yes, you added a question mark, still When would be a good time to [whatever] **?** is a question form. And it is not lengthy.

Answer (score 2):

> "Please let me know when would be a good time to..."

The subordinate interrogative has the main clause interrogative equivalent as "When would be a good time to X?". In this analysis, I take the clause in the subject questioned with **When** as the ***subject of the specifying "be"***. It’s in the usual subject position, before the head verb of the clause. And can be answered by replacing "When" with a PP as in ***After dinner** would be a good time to X.*

As noted by others, it is perfectly idiomatic.

> "Please let me know when a good time would be to..."

The subordinate interrogative has the main clause interrogative equivalent as *When would a good time to X be*" where "**When"** functions as the ***complement of specifying "be"*** (Non-subject questioned). Here **"When"** is in the **prenucleus position** and can be answered in this format: **A good time to X would be __**

Answer (score 1):

> I wrote: *Please let me know when would be a good time to...*

> Correction: *Please let me know when a good time would be to...*

OK, I got it wrong above so I should post a more detailed (and better) answer. I wasn't totally wrong -- subject-auxiliary inversion is still involved, but so are other rules, which I didn't notice.

This OQ uses *Please let me know* as the matrix clause with the embedded question complement. I've tried it with several others and as long as it's an embedded question, the phenomenon's the same, so I'll continue to use it. On the other hand, "to ..." is an uninspiring infinitive, so let's use *to leave*, which fits  many contexts. And let's put a subject back on the infinitive, just to keep things straight; I'll use *us* as the subject (again, fitting many contexts), and add the *for* subject marker to go with the *to* verb marker of the infinitive complementizer. Viz, with bracketed clauses:

- *[Please let [me know [when would be a good time [for us to leave]]]]*.

Perfectly grammatical, but irregular. There are **two** auxiliary verbs (*would* and *be*) in the question, and **both** of them are inverted, instead of just the first one:

- *Please let me know when would a good time be for us to leave*

[Both of these are not normal embedded questions, which don't invert auxiliaries](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/51126/15299). Without inversion, we get the following

- *Please let me know when a good time for us to leave would be.*

as well as the following, with Extraposition from NP detaching the infinitive

- *Please let me know when a good time would be for us to leave.*

from the subject NP *a good time for us to leave*.

Other possibilities abound; *What time* (or often just *What*, with *time* implicit in *a good time*), for instance, produces a different cascade of possibilities.

But not all of them are grammatical, or at least regular -- though modals are such a charley foxtrot it's hard to distinguish. For instance, there's only one variant (with *would* fronted but not *be*) that allows extraposition *it* in the question:

- *When would (it) be a good time for us to leave?*
- *When would be (*it) a good time for us to leave?*
- *When would (*it) a good time for us to leave be?*

Though varieties of embedded clauses allow Extraposition:

- *Please let me know when (it) would be a good time for us to leave*

This is a fairly sticky, though easily constructed, problem, and it's not surprising that an online free service didn't get it all.

Comment: Glad I bumped into this answer