# Is there a term for a sentence that suggests a question but isn't one?

Tags: terminology

I've noticed some sentences or phrases that suggest a question that people tend to accidentally end with a question mark. Examples: "I wonder why" or "The question is what we should do now".

Is there a term for such a sentence or for the error of punctuating them with a question mark?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the term you're looking for is **indirect question**.

> a question that is reported to other people in speech or writing, rather than the exact words of the original question, for example 'He asked me what was wrong.'  ([Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/indirect-question))

Various ESL sites specifically cite the "I wonder..." case as an example of an indirect question.

> [Example](http://www.eslbase.com/grammar/indirect-questions):
>
> Direct question: Where have they been?
>
> Indirect question: I wonder where they have been?

Notably, that example does use the question mark at the end.  It is not always considered incorrect; it really depends on whether you want it to be perceived as a question or a statement.  For more info about that, see [this related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52554/question-mark-when-ending-sentence-with-i-wonder) and its answers.

Comment: Shouldn't the second one end with a period?

Comment: @Mehrdad Yes. A question mark converts it to a declarative question. _'Can you read Quentin's last sentence? His writing is worse than mine.' _'I wonder where they have been'?

Answer (score -1):

Is that a ["rhetorical question"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question)?  I think it is.

Comment: No, a rhetorical question is somewhat the opposite — a question asked to make a point, not a statement made to raise a question.