# "I wonder how old he is?"

Tags: punctuation

Is it correct to end the following sentence with a question mark? I am asking a question about end punctuation. "I wonder how old he is?"

Comment: As well as the nominated duplicate, there is also a question about [**ending** with "I wonder"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52554/question-mark-when-ending-sentence-with-i-wonder) which contains useful information.

Comment: I wouldn't do it, because it's just a statement: “I wonder how old he is.“ If you use a question mark and really ask somebody it would simply be “Do you know how old he is?“ or just “How old is he?“

Comment: @Harmless Psycho The sentence **may** be declarative, or it **may** be a declarative question, inviting an answer. These are differentiated by intonation in speech, and by the inclusion or otherwise of a question mark in print.