# Where does the verb go on this question? Is it even a reported question?

Tags: verbs, word-order, subject-verb-inversion, indirect-question, wh-questions

I understand that when I report a question, I put the subject back in front of the verb, as in:  "He asked if she was going to be late."

But I always get puzzled when it comes to reporting a question with a question. (In fact I'm not even sure this is reported speech, but I think it is, because I'm reporting my own doubts.)

My starting point is the question:

> What is the task for the afternoon class?

But now I want to ask if anyone in a group knows what the task is. Which of the following alternatives would be grammatical?

> (a) Does anyone know what is the task for the afternoon class?
>   (b) Does anyone know what the task is for the afternoon class?
>   (c) Does anyone know what the task for the afternoon class is?

Intuitively, I would pick (c), but I don't know if that is the correct choice, and I certainly don't know why.

Can anyone tell me which of the options is correct and why?

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/608581/2085).

Answer (score 8):

All three versions occur, though they don't falute the same.

- **(c)** is the canonic source, with simple *Wh*-fronting, leaving *is* at the end of the sentence:

  > *does anyone know [the task for the afternoon **is** `what`]?* ==>
  >
  > *does anyone know [`what` the task for the afternoon **is**]?*
- **(b)** is a further variation on (c), with the prepositional phrase *for the afternoon*, which modifies *task*, moved (by the rule of "Extraposition from NP") from right after *task* to the end of the sentence.

  > *does anyone know [`what` the task **for the afternoon** is]?* ==>
  >
  > *does anyone know [`what` the task is **for the afternoon**]?*
  >
  > In this position, it balances the *is*. This is an esthetic improvement, not a grammatical one. English doesn't like long complex sentences that end with *is* (like (**c)** -- the effect is rather like hearing the first two musical notes of a 3-note chord progression; you keep waiting for the other note to drop.
- **(a)**, on the other hand, is a variant of (c) with Subject/Auxiliary Inversion performed, the same way it would be on a real, non-embedded, information-seeking question. 
  It's not proper written English, but is very common in speech, where it has an [additional pragmatic usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/50012/15299) to signal that the speaker really **does** want an answer to the question, and not just a *Yes* or *No*. (Notice, by the way, that this also has the effect of keeping the *is* away from the end of the sentence, which is another reason it occurs so frequently.)

  > *does anyone know [`what` the task for the afternoon **is**]?* ==>
  >
  > *does anyone know [`what` **is** the task for the afternoon]?*  (Tell me, please; I really need to know)

Comment: +1 for *falute*. But shouldn't it be "falute to the same height"?

Comment: That's perfectly cromulent, given that it's an [Up/Down metaphor](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf).

Comment: i really appreciate your answer mr lawler, im the type of person that needs this exact type of explanation to really understand something. you couldnt have done it any better. thanks a lot