# Why do some people say “We need to know what is it”?

Tags: questions

I notice a lot of people—even native speakers sometimes—change the order of certain words when asking a question (e.g., “We don't know what is it”).

As far as I know, it should be “We don't know what it is.”

Is changing the order of certain words, as in the first example (is–it), correct at all?

Comment: Personally, I am a native speaker and I’ve never heard another native speaker say “need to know what is it”. It sounds like a strong marker of ESL to my ear.

Comment: @DanBron What does ESL mean? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Fabian Someone who is learning ***E**nglish* as a ***S**econd* ***L**anguage*, aka a non-native speaker.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does the verb go on this question? Is it even a reported question?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93371/where-does-the-verb-go-on-this-question-is-it-even-a-reported-question) {[Does she know what it is all about? or Does she know what is it all about?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/412993/does-she-know-what-it-is-all-about-or-does-she-know-what-is-it-all-about) was closed as a duplicate of this.} Of course, 'Does she know – what is it all about?' is acceptable.