# Question inversion in English like in German?

Tags: questions, subject-verb-inversion

In German, one has to invert questions in a sub-sentence. Not doing so feels wrong in English to me, is it allowed in English too or is that strictly illegal grammar?

### Example

"Now the question is only, how accessible is the XML structure." (not inverted)

"Now the question is only, how accessible the XML structure is." (inverted)

### Corrected Second Example

"I wonder, how does he do it?" (inverted)

"I wonder how he does it." (not inverted)

Comment: Where do you see the inversion in "I wonder how he does it?"

Comment: The non-inverted form - effectively quoting the question -  is acceptable, but needs a 'stronger' form of punctuation than a comma to introduce it. "I wonder - how does he do it?"

Comment: @BillJ: You are right, the second example is incorrect. The German way would be "I wonder, how he it does." but that is obviously wrong.

Comment: @Konrad: Your second example is fine; you just switched the labels. In English, you need to add an auxiliary verb when you invert a sentence. Which means: "I wonder how he does it" is the non-inverted form and "I wonder how does he do it" is the inverted form.

Comment: @PeterShor: Thanks, I switched the labels around. So both are fine?

Comment: @KonradHöffner The uninverted order is the norm, but some varieties of English allow subordinate interrogatives with subject-auxiliary inversion in contexts of strong question-orientation. I wouldn't say that "I wonder how does he do it? "meets that criterion, but it sounds OK to me.

Comment: It's complicated — as @KateBunting says, in formal writing you need different punctuation to introduce the inverted form. In speech, both are fine, although you'd put a small pause before the inverted form.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies! The more I think about it, the more confused I get so I'm not even sure anymore what my problem really is, because both questions and sub-sentences get inverted in German. I will clarify the question once I know exactly what I actually mean, sorry for the bad question.

Comment: Punctuation is not crucial. Compare: "She asked what had she done wrong" and "She asked what she had done wrong". Both perfectly grammatical in writing and both without any punctuation.

Comment: @BillJ: Perfect! If both are fine then I can just use the one that feels more intuitive coming from German.

Comment: @KonradHöffner Yes, you can, but as I said, the uninverted order is the norm in subordinate interrogatives. The inverted order is, perhaps, non-standard, but it is certainly found in Standard English.

Comment: It's quite common, and [this answer covers embedded question variation in inversion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/50012/15299). Inversion appears to be used for pragmatic purposes, like anything that's both meaningless and predictable.

Comment: Yes: that's the "contexts of strong question-orientation" that I referred to earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two distinct processes affecting word order in questions:

1. Subject-verb inversion. This shows up in yes-no questions, but only auxiliary verbs are typically inverted in modern English, so a form of “do” is added with non-auxiliaries (part of a phenomenon called “do-support”). *Is the appointment at 9:30?* is a yes-no question with subject-verb inversion.
2. Wh-fronting. Interrogative words like *what, when, whom, how* come at the front of their clause, even if their grammatical role is something that would normally come in a different position (like the object or complement of the verb). So we put *when* at the start of ***When** is the appointment?* even though an answer will use a word order like *The appointment is **at 9:30***.

A typical non-embedded question has both wh-fronting and subject verb inversion (*How are you doing?*) unless the subject is a wh-word (*Who is at the door?*).

An embedded question shows wh-fronting, but usually does not show subject verb inversion: *I asked them how they were doing* or *I want to know when the appointment is.* Inversion (*I asked them how were they doing*, *I want to know when is the appointment*) is sometimes an acceptable alternative in some dialects, but as a rule, inversion is not preferred in this context in formal English. However, using a comma before the inverted clause often increases the acceptability in standard written English: “I want to know, when is the appointment?”